# Join variables to get a percentage

Tags: algorithms, random-variables, percentages, mixing-variables

I've been working on something for P2P and I got stuck with a formula for group leadership chance.

I have a few factors:

```
batteryPercentage (variable, integer, from 0 to 100)

numRoundsSinceLastLeadership (variable, integer, describes the number of times since I was a leader)

timeSinceLastLeadership (variable, integer, number of milliseconds since I was a leader)

preferredLeadershipCycle (constant, integer, 5 minutes in millisseconds, 3 * 10^5)

randomFactor (variable, integer, a random number from 0 to 100)
```

And I'm stuck for a few hours on how I can join all these variables to achieve a percentage (0 - 100) of the chance of the device being a leader in the next round.

Can someone help me to find some content to learn or help me to achieve a formula for this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What are the conditions/requirements to be group leader? Is there any sort of scheme to decide? Can the group leader have no battery?

Comment: These factors I mentioned would be the requirements, joining them with a higher = better factor would result in a higher chance to be a leader (the expected formula result)

Comment: These appear to be measurements or metrics, not criteria/requirements. An example requirement might be something like "If batteryPercentage=0 then can't be leader".

Also can devices in a group communicate. (ie could we just do a simple additive score, compare, normalize and determine?) 

Is random factor something fixed after the device joins the group? Is it just some random number?

Comment: I want to use these measurements as criteria for a chance to be a leader in the next round. Example: higher battery percentage, higher number of rounds since I was a leader, higher number of milliseconds since I was a leader, random number, if I join all of them, the higher it gets, higher the chance for me to be a leader. I just wanted to sum all these measurements in a formula to get a 0 - 100% chance to be a leader with a higher = better criteria for the measurements. And yes, devices in a group communicate only with the leader. But they need to candidate to be a leader, that's the criteria

Comment: At that point why not just have everyone send a score to the leader that is just the sum of these metrics, the leader takes that score and divides by the sum of scores of the group. Probability of being leader is device's score divided by sum of scores of devices. Does it work? Sure, there will be a chance and higher in one metric means higher probability. Is it a good idea? Probably not, but without some weighting/preference I'm not sure a good idea can be formulated.

Comment: The idea is that there's no leader, devices can candidate to be a leader based on these percentages.

Comment: How do you prevent multiple leaders from being declared?

Comment: You can't, if a device doesn't propose to be a leader, he joins randomly an existing group, there can be multiple groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is **a** leader per group then the devices have to communicate in some way to make sure that there isn't a way for multiple devices to declare themselves leader.

A general way to do this, though again probably not the optimal/acceptable way if there are more conditions/preferences, would be to just make some score add up all the scores from devices that could be leader and make a probability out of that. If $p_i$ is the probability of device $i$ being leader and $s_i$ is the score of the $i^{th}$ device, $\lambda$ is a constant defined to ensure that all scores are greater than 0, $l_{ji}$ is the measure of the $i^{th}$ device, finally let $w_j$ be some weighting factor for the $j^{th}$ metric:
$$ s_i = \lambda+\sum_j w_j l_{ji}$$
$$ p_i = \frac{s_i}{\sum_i s_i}$$

For simplicity in this problem I think $\lambda = 1$ and $w_j = 1$ works since you have no negative metrics.

Another approach if you want to form multiple groups:
$$ p_i = \frac{s_i}{\max(s)}$$

Where max(s) is the maximum achievable score.

Comment: Thanks to your ideas I got somewhere near with this JavaScript code: https://repl.it/repls/CandidDarkgrayBot